# create a new folder everyday as per UTC time in my s3 bucket and save json files in it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create a new folder everyday as per UTC time in my s3 bucket, the dict should be saved in json format in that folder

**My_Attempt**

```
            import pytz
            import datetime
            import botocore
            import boto3
            
            s3 = session.resource('s3')
            config['S3_BUCKET'] = 'my_data'
            # Get the current date and time in UTC
            utc_now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
            today = utc_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            folder_name = "json_files_" + today
            my_array = '{"id": "0"}'
            # Check if the folder for today already exists
            try:
                s3.head_bucket(Bucket=config['S3_BUCKET'], Key=folder_name + "/") #head_object(Bucket=config['S3_BUCKET'], Key=folder_name + "/")
            except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e: #boto3.exceptions.ClientError as e: #s3.exceptions.ClientError as e:
                # If the folder does not exist, create it
                if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "404":
                    s3.put_object(Bucket=config['S3_BUCKET'], Key=folder_name + "/")
                else:
                    # Raise any other errors
                    raise
            key = folder_name + "/" + str(my_array['id']) + ".json"
            print('key -> ',key)
            s3.put_object(Bucket="my-bucket", Key=key, Body=my_array)
```

**ERROR**
I tried both 'head_bucket' and 'head_object'

```
's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'head_bucket' 
's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'head_object'
```

How can I improve the code and debug the code?

Comment: You want `s3 = session.client('s3')`, and `head_object`.  That said, there is rarely a need to create a "folder" in S3, just generate the object you want with the desired prefix.  S3 doesn't really have a concept of folders, just common prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `s3 = session.resource('s3')` with `s3 = session.client('s3')` and it works as suggested by @Anon Conward